# Why we use setAnchorView() with VideoView

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand working with Videos in android studio there's one problem, I didn't get why we use anchor method

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an anchor as a heavy object that keeps the video view in its place throughout the period of the use of your app .Basically it is used for holding VideoView's position.